# Calling a function using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on application in AngularJs

Here is my code :

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main" class="containerWrap">
..
..
..
<p ng-bind-html="parseMsg(msg)"></p>
..
..
```

The parseMsg function passes the msg filled by the user to the controller JS defined as follows :

```
this.parseMsg=function(msg){
...
...
    if(msg['subtype']==FILES_UPLOADING){
        $scope.showUploadOptions=true;
        var per=parseInt(msg['text']);
        if(per==100)
            msg['text']='<div ng-if="showUploadOptions"><img ng-src="logo.png"  ng-click="main.cancelFileUpload(chat,msg_id)"/></div>';
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(msg['text']);
    }
...
...
...
};
```

Chat and msg_id being passed to the main.cancelFileUpload are stored previously as:

```
$scope.chat = (object)
$scope.msg_id =(object) 

this.cancelFileUpload=function(chat,msg_id){
        alert("Cancel clicked ");
        delete this.retryUploadFiles[msg_id];
        delete chat.msgs[msg_id];
    };
```

What I am trying to do is cancel the file upload being sent during the server request using a click on an image.

This ng-click is not responding. It doesn't give an error but doesn't function properly either.

Can anyone help identify the issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could try another view of the problem. Particularly I don't like HTML in Javascript, Why don try have the Button or Image hidden with ng-class, It's more cheap and less dirty for your future maintenance.

Comment: It's not doing anything because angular has not been informed of this change, and hasn't run a $digest cycle. You basically need to call $scope.$apply, but that's not very recommended and you should probably find a better solution. And you're missing the closing quotes at `class="containerWrap>`

Answer (score 0):

`ngBindHtml` don't compile your HTML. So, all angular directives from your dynamic HTML(ng-if, ng-src, ng-click, etc..) will not work.

To really compile your html you can use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service like that:

```
$compile(html)($scope)
```

**But it's not a true way** for angular. If you want to modify DOM structure - you need to use directives. In your case you can include that html to template itself instead of add it dynamically:

```
<div ng-show="showYourHtml">
    <img ng-src="logo.png"
         ng-click="main.cancelFileUpload(chat,msg_id)"/>
</div>
```

And your controler:

```
...
if(conditions){
    $scope.showYourHtml = true;
}
...
```